# How to go to a new line in python while using unicode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Thanks for opening to help, I am a beginner programmer for a school major work and decided to do a checkout application. It isnt anything too fancy, most aspects are hard coded with some pieces being read from editable txt files. I am currently making the main system of the application where the user is able to select the item where it adds to their cart as well as checks to see if it is already in the cart to modify the cart as I don't want double ups on a piece of clothing.

###Tasks I am stuck on

- I am not able to get it to write to a new line (around 234) where it should accept \n, it doesn't work, rather it displays a box as if it doesn't understand the character. Possibly could be the character system I am using but I am not too sure.
  If something is in the cart and another thing is added, It isn't able to go back and modify what's already in the cart. (I am able to do it when nothing else is added after as It just replaces the text).
  my teacher / project supervisor also said to add an admin function where they are able to modify the Items, prices and pictures(if I add any) through a txt file.
- I am also wanting the cart to be on a scrolling screen that updates in size when necessary but this is an optional feature that I am going to look for tutorials unless one kind person can explain.
  The top rectangles are meant to take to another page with more options to chose from and I can't think of how to code this bit.
  I also kind of want date and time to be printed on the bottom right but this is a minor piece
  I know its a lot but I've got until late June to complete everything. Any advice is appreciated as it is still a big work in progress and I am only new to the language. Please let me know if you need any other information related.

Thanks Heaps!!!!! #Edit : added the picture Picture of the screen as is

```
# window ----------------------------------------
"""
This file is the executable file which calls all other files including the
full application.
"""
#The following imports are modules which have prewritten
#functions which I am able to use. They came predownloaded
#with python as well as downloading some from pygame.org
import pygame, sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from collections import Counter as count
from datetime import datetime
import time
import string


#import read
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

#setting window
from pygame.locals import *
#The following are Constants which are defined here for easier maintanence
click = bool
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('LeVOGUE')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800), 0, 32)
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 650), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

                                     
run = 2
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 70)
font3 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
base_font2 = pygame.font.Font(None, 160)
Item = ''
Item_rect = pygame.Rect(780, 33, 400, 547)



Colour = pygame.Color(0,0,0)
found =False
#key_text_num = 2
s = " "
fh =open("user_info.txt", "r")


keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
click = pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN
Volume = True
active = False
#tick_active = False


#This is responsible fo importing the mixer module
from pygame import mixer
#Load music file
mixer.music.load("MainMenuMusic.mp3")
#play music file
mixer.music.play()



sc1_num = 0
sc1_price = 0
sc2_num = 0
sc2_price = 0



        
        


def Main_sales():
#this area of the code was reused from a previous file
#which is an example of the RAD approach.

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Start Code applied from previous programs~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     
    global click
    global Item
    global active
    global bags
    global current_time
    global found
    global count
    global s
    global fh
    global i_a
    global key_text_num
    global Item_rect 
    global sc1_num
    global sc1_price
    global sc2_num
    global sc2_price    
        
#This checkbox is imported from a module found within the LeVOGUE folder
#The checkbox file is imported above and called with the function checkbox
    

    
    while True:
        #Defining Quit
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                print("Quit")
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~End Code applied from tutorial~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

            #if key escape key is pressed, Quit    
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
               
                    
            #if click, click is true
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True

           
            

            if click:
                print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        
        #Background colour
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

        text_surface = font3.render(Item, True, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text_surface, (Item_rect.x+20 , Item_rect.y +100))
        
        
        #mouse position
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        #This section of code was applied from a tutorial which I followed
        #It was used to allow me to create rectangular buttons although it was
        #heavily modified to add functionality to different buttons
        
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Start code applied from tutorial ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  


        



        b_w = 180
        b_h = 70
        
        b2_x = 274
        b2_y = 562
        b2_w = 140
        b2_h = 65

        b3_x = 55
        b3_y = 200
        
        b4_x = 275
        b4_y = 200
        
        b5_x = 490
        b5_y = 200
       
        b6_x = 55
        b6_y = 290
        
        b7_x = 275
        b7_y = 290
        
        b8_x = 490
        b8_y = 290
       
        b9_x = 55
        b9_y = 380
        
        b10_x = 275
        b10_y = 380
       
        b11_x = 490
        b11_y = 380
       
        b12_x = 55
        b12_y = 470

        b13_x = 275
        b13_y = 470

        b14_x = 490
        b14_y = 470
         
    



        
        button_2 = pygame.Rect(b2_x, b2_y, b2_w, b2_h)
        
        button_3 = pygame.Rect( b3_x, b3_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_4 = pygame.Rect( b4_x, b4_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_5 = pygame.Rect( b5_x, b5_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_6 = pygame.Rect( b6_x, b6_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_7 = pygame.Rect( b7_x, b7_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_8 = pygame.Rect( b8_x, b8_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_9 = pygame.Rect( b9_x, b9_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_10 = pygame.Rect( b10_x, b10_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_11 = pygame.Rect( b11_x, b11_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_12 = pygame.Rect( b12_x, b12_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_13 = pygame.Rect( b13_x, b13_y ,b_w, b_h)
        button_14 = pygame.Rect( b14_x, b14_y ,b_w, b_h)
        


        
        #What happens if the mouse click is over buttons listed above
      
        if button_2.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
                print("button2")
                
                import MainMenu

        if button_3.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:

                #while (sc_num < 10):
                if (f"Scrunchie            {sc1_num}    ${sc1_price} ") in Item:
                    Item = Item[:-29]
                    

                sc1_num = sc1_num+1
                sc1_price = sc1_price+15
                Item = Item + (f"Scrunchie            {sc1_num}    ${sc1_price} \n")
                print(" Button3")
               
        if button_4.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
                if (f"Scrunchie            {sc2_num}    ${sc2_price}") in Item:
                    Item = Item[:-39]
                    

                sc2_num = sc2_num+1
                sc2_price = sc2_price+15
                Item = Item + (f"Scrunchie2            {sc2_num}    ${sc2_price}")
                print(" Button4")
               
        if button_5.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button5")
               
        if button_6.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button6")
               
        if button_7.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button7")
               
        if button_8.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button8")
               
        if button_9.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button9")
               
        if button_10.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button10")
               
        if button_11.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button11")
        if button_12.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button12")
        if button_13.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button13")
        if button_14.collidepoint(mx, my):
            if click:
               print(" Button14")


     
        
        text_surface_Cart = font.render("Cart", True, (0,0,0))
        text_surface_Item = font.render( "Item                         Qty      Price", True, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text_surface_Cart, (790,50))
        screen.blit(text_surface_Item, (790, 100))

        #for Button 2
        text_surface_Enter = font2.render("Enter", True, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text_surface_Enter, pygame.Rect((280, 565), (120, 70)))
                                          


        
        #Cart
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,Colour,pygame.Rect(780,30,400,550),2)
        #button 2; Enter
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour , button_2, 2)
        #Draw boxes for the number buttons
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_3, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_4, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_5, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_6, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_7, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_8, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_9, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_10, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_11, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_12, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_13, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Colour, button_14, 2)

        screen.blit((font3.render("Scrunchie1", True, (0,0,0))),(b3_x+20, b3_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Scrunchie2", True, (0,0,0))),(b4_x+20, b4_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Scrunchie3", True, (0,0,0))),(b5_x+20, b5_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Scrunchie4", True, (0,0,0))),(b6_x+20, b6_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Scrunchie5", True, (0,0,0))),(b7_x+20, b7_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Shirt6", True, (0,0,0))),(b8_x+20, b8_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Shirt7", True, (0,0,0))),(b9_x+20, b9_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Shirt8", True, (0,0,0))),(b10_x+20, b10_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Shirt9", True, (0,0,0))),(b11_x+20, b11_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Pants10", True, (0,0,0))),(b12_x+20, b12_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Pants11", True, (0,0,0))),(b13_x+20, b13_y+15))
        screen.blit((font3.render("Pants11", True, (0,0,0))),(b14_x+20, b14_y+15))
       
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ End Code applied from tutorial~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
        

        ButtonBolt = pygame.image.load("LionsHEAD.png")
        ButtonBolt = pygame.transform.scale(ButtonBolt, (120, 120))
        screen.blit(ButtonBolt, (20,15))

            

        text_surface_LeVOGUE = font2.render("LeVOGUE", True, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text_surface_LeVOGUE, (140,55))


        Key_Rect = pygame.Rect(260, 125, 230, 40)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0) , Key_Rect, 2)

        
        Left_select_Rect = pygame.Rect(208, 125, 40, 40)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), Left_select_Rect , 2)

        text_surface_Left_select = font2.render("<", True, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text_surface_Left_select, (215,118))

        Right_select_Rect = pygame.Rect(502, 125, 40, 40)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), Right_select_Rect , 2)

        text_surface_Left_select = font2.render(">", True, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text_surface_Left_select, (510,118))
        



        


        
        #CART
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,Colour,pygame.Rect(780,30,400,550),2)


        
        
        
        click = False
        #update screen

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        mainClock.tick(60)

    



#The following code was derived from a tutorial which allows the application
#to quit without causing any error codes. 

#~~~~~~~~~~~~Start code applied from tutorial~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
def Quit():
    running = True
    while running:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
#~~~~~~~~~~~ End Code applied from tutorial~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        
        

        

#run the main menu
Main_sales()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: You would likely get more useful help if you simplify your example. Not many will read all that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line

```
text_surface = font3.render(Item, True, (0,0,0))
```

You're using the pygame font renderer. The pygame.font.Font/SysFont().render() does not support multiple line text.

This is stated in the documentation [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render).

> The text can only be a single line: newline characters are not rendered.